# Como customizar o retorno de um atributo no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

No `Laravel`, eu sei que os atributos podem retornar um objeto do tipo `Carbon\Carbon` (uma extensão do `DateTime` do php), caso o campo seja created_at ou updated_at.

Exemplo:

```
$usuario = Usuario::find(1);

// Não é uma string, é um Carbon\Carbon(object)
$usuario->created_at->format('d/m/Y');
```

Porém eu gostaria de fazer isso com um atributo do tipo `tinyint`.

Por exemplo, no model `Usuario` eu tenho o atributo retornado da tabela chamado `ativo`.

Ao invés de retornar `1` ou `0` do model, eu gostaria que ela já me retornasse `"sim"` ou `"não"`.

É possível fazer isso no `Laravel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa definir um atributo usando um recurso do `Laravel` chamado de [Eloquent Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators), no qual você define o nome do campo, colocando `get` no início e `attribute` no final.

São os chamados `Model Accessors` do `Laravel`.

Então, faça assim no seu model:

```
public function getAtivoTextoAttribute()
{
      return $this->attributes['ativo'] == 1 ? 'Sim' : 'Não';
}
```

Daí, basta você fazer a chamada:

```
$usuario = Usuario::find(1);

echo $usuario->ativo_texto;
```

Nesse caso, eu preferi criar um atributo com o nome que não colida com o nome real da tabela, pois creio que essa seja a melhor maneira de trabalhar.

Se você opcionalmente quiser que, quando retornar a consulta em `json`, esse "campo costumizado" aparece, basta fazer assim:

```
class Usuario
{
      protected $appends = ['ativo_texto']

      public function getAtivoTextoAttribute(){ /* definição */ }
}
```

Comment: Um link pra documentação e utilizar o nome desse recurso seria mais interessante. `atributo método mágico` pode gerar confusões com o `__get` do PHP.